# SAP 4.6C and webservices

Tags: web-services, rpc, sap-basis, sap-r3

Is it possible to provide RFCs (remote function calls, aka remote procedure calls) as web services with SAP 4.6C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly possible (not as simply as ECC6, at least)

you can either create a custom webservice that call the RFC and expose it, or use the [SAP Business Connector](https://websmp102.sap-ag.de/sbc-download) that expose RFC-enabled function and BAPI as webservice. This tool is  available to download from SAP service.

[this question on SDN](https://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=959440)

regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

Guillaume is correct. Beside SAP Business Connector (which is quite lean), you can also expose the RFC as Web Service with SAP PI (SAP Process Integration) if available on your landscape.
A lot of other EAI solutions that have a Rfc enabled adapter are also capable of doing it (e.g. TIBCO Businessworks).